# Fill ListView from database (LINQ)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listview

I have a table filled with customers, which has their name, street, city, zipcode, etc.
Now in my program I have a listview in which I want to show these exact items.
So every row will have a new customer, with their name, street, city, zipcode, etc.

I've been trying for a while but can't figure it out.

I have this but it's not working:

```
List<customers> itemsList = new List<customers>();
        itemsList = (from value in database.customers select value).ToList();

        listNewContractCustomers.ItemsSource = itemsList;
```

Where customers is the table in the database.

Comment: will you use detailed view?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean... I'm pretty new at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView does not autogenerate columns but [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) does.

Comment: Thanks! I've switched to DataGrid and it did the job! Thank you very much